# How can we get selected menu with multiple pages

Tags: javascript, html, django

Please see the below screenshot

[image]

I want to get selected this contacts menu if I click on the View contacts page which is redirect me to another page. (see screenshot-2)

[image]

for contacts menu it's working fine if I click on to the contacts menu but if I click on to the view contact it's not showing me contacts menu selected. So how can I get selected if I am in another page? basically I want this functionality for all menus.

Here is the code :

javascript

```
<script>

   const currentLocation = location.href;
   const menuItem = document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar-menu a');
   const menuLength = menuItem.length
    for(let i=0; i<menuLength;i++){

       if(menuItem[i].href === currentLocation){
         alert("in if condition");
         alert(menuItem[i].href);
          menuItem[i].className = "active"
       }
```

sidebar-menubar code

```
                <div class="sidebar">
                   <div class="sidebar-logo">
                 <a href="#"> <img src="{% static 'images/paramLogo_sideBar.png' %}" alt=""></a>
                </div>
              <div class="sidebar-menu">
                 <ul>
                     <li>
                    <a class="nav-link homecls" href="{% url 'home' %}"> <img class="sidebar-icon" src="{% static 'images/home.png' %}" alt="">Home</a>
                        </li>
                         <li>
                   <a class="nav-link contactscls" href="{% url 'broadcastlist' %}"> <img class="sidebar-icon" src="{% static 'images/contacts.png' %}" alt="">Contacts</a>
                        </li>
                         <li>
                   <a class="nav-link messagescls" href="{% url 'howToSend' %}"> <img class="sidebar-icon" src="{% static 'images/messages.png' %}" alt="">Messages</a>
                  </li>
                <li>
               <a class="nav-link dashboardcls" href="{% url 'dashboardSMS' %}"> <img class="sidebar-icon" src="{% static 'images/dashboardIcon.png' %}" alt="">Dashboard</a>
                 </li>
                  </div>
```